# Global flag to turn on/off validation in Prismatic/Schema?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, plumatic-schema

During development I would like to enable validation for all functions that are defined with schema.core/defn, instead of having to annotate them with `:^:always-validate`. Is this possible with this library?

Something like this doesn't work, probably because meta-data is only added during compile-time:

```
(def dev false)

;; example of schema validation
(sm/defn ^{:always-validate dev}
  add :- s/Num
  [a :- s/Num b :- s/Num]
  (+ a b))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to do what I want:

```
(s/set-fn-validation! false)
```